# orb glass distorted effect using css

Tags: css

i was going through the site https://lionsgoodnews.com/article01/  where there is an animation where it has a orb glass effect where the side of the orbs will distort anything thats behind them. Was wondering is this doable on css? The site seems to be using canvas / threejs to power that effect. Not too sure what to be looking for the web for that kind of effect. Would appreciate if anyone would be able to help point me to the that direction.